# How to convert something to json using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

so long story short i was wondering if it was possible to encode or display the output of a GET request to show in a structured way in json.
For example, if i do:

```
wiki = requests.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars', headers={'Content-Type' : 'application/json'})
```

the encoding is "text/html; charset=UTF-8" and appears as a big block of text back when using print(wiki.text).
I know there is a json method in the requests library but that is only for data that has been outputted as json and will be turned into a Python dict is used.

Comment: You might want to use [Wikipedia's JSON api](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Tutorial).

Comment: Thanks, that did help and i was looking for somekind of json output but wanted to see if i could turn the data from the get request on the page above and format it to json

Comment: @Michael did my answer help you? Accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is use existing Wiki API. It rightfully for other sites.

If target site doesn't have API, you can use different html parsers. For example, `Beautiful Soup`. During that parsing process you cat get data with json format.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint
import requests

response = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
header = soup.find('h1', class_='firstHeading').text
summary = soup.find('p', class_='').text

pprint({
    'header': header,
    'summary': summary
})

# {'header': 'Star Wars',
#  'summary': 'Star Wars is an American epic space-opera media franchise created '
#             ...}
```